# Glassfish using Saxon instead of Xalan, XSLT 2.0, Java

Tags: java, pdf, glassfish, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a problem with transforming a XML (TEI P5) to PDF. My Stylesheet is from TEI https://github.com/TEIC/Stylesheets and I call the file fo/fo.xsl. When I transform my XML using Oxygen and Saxon there is no Problem, the PDF will be generated. But in my J2EE application the transform does not work. I think because of the XSLT 2.0. So i wanted to change to an other parser. I downloaded Saxon 9HE and included it in my project. Then I experimented and changed the java call and it looks now like this:

```
    String inputXSL2 = "/de/we/parser/xslt/fo/fo.xsl";
    String inputXML2 = "/de/we/parser/testfiles/Presentation.xml";

    Source xsltTarget = new StreamSource(inputXSL2);
    try {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        tFactory.setURIResolver(new XsltURIResolver());
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltTarget);
        Controller controller = (net.sf.saxon.Controller) transformer;
        Configuration configuration = controller.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setConfigurationProperty(FeatureKeys.PRE_EVALUATE_DOC_FUNCTION, Boolean.TRUE);

        Source source = transformer.getURIResolver().resolve(inputXML2, "");
        DocumentInfo newdoc = configuration.buildDocument(source);
        configuration.getGlobalDocumentPool().add(newdoc, inputXML2);

        Source streamSource = null;
        StreamResult resultTarget = null;

        streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML2));
        resultTarget = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(streamSource, resultTarget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


class XsltURIResolver implements URIResolver {

@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/de/we/parser/xslt/fo/" + href);
        StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(inputStream);
        ss.setSystemId("/de/we/parser/xslt/fo/" + href);
        return ss;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The error is:
I/O error reported by XML parser processing /de/we/parser/xslt/fo/fo.xsl:
  \de\we\parser\xslt\fo\fo.xsl (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
But the file exists so i don't know whats the problem.

Had a lot other version where I tried to use Saxon, but the result was never a generated pdf :(
Need some help please

Comment: You say you have it working. Please also post the working version in your question so we can compare it to the not-working version.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't crosspost to multiple lists.

You asked the same question here

https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/5849?r=5851#message-5851

where I answered it.